# Django login not working

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I have a really weird issue here. I'm using my local development server right now, and I'm working on the user account aspect of my site.

I thought I had it worked out, but when I try to access `@login_required` views I fill in the login information, and am redirected back to the login page everytime.  When I try to login to the admin site (to verify everything is good on the backend) the same thing happens: I put in a correct username and password, and am redirected back to the login page.

I verified via the shell that the username I'm using for the admin site is a super user, is staff, and is active.  In my settings I have `Authentication` and `Session` middleware enabled, as well as `django.contrib.auth` and `django.contrib.sessions` in my installed apps.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you have cookies enabled in your browser?

Comment: Could you give us more details on what really happens? Open Google Chrome, hit F12, go to "_Network_" tab, refresh the page, turn "_Preserve Logs upon Navigation_" (should be big gray dot at the bottom) and tell us: 1) what is the status code the page responded with, 2) what was the response code of the page, when you provided username and password, and then sent the login form, 3) was there any redirect during no. 2?. Also try resetting superuser password by invoking [proper `manage.py` command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#changepassword) and try again.

Comment: Cookies are enabled, and I should've mentioned I tried changing the password a couple times as well.  I just checked out the network tab in chrome, and there's the POST when I send the form with a 302 code, and then there is in fact a redirect GET back to /admin.

Comment: have you enabled the secure middleware and accessing from http protocol?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it-- I had set `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` to `True` in my settings.py, but since I'm using the development server SSL isn't enabled it would just redirect to the same page.  Thanks for the help guys you got me searching around.